# Azure Notification Hub Registration from Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to send a Push Notification with a text that says "Email Read" to individual users when the email they send through my Android App is read.

I send the emails through SendGrid API,and I have setup an Azure Function webhook endpoint that gets called when the email is read.

I can attach a Notification Hub registration Id and a GCM Token to the emails which gets passed back to me via the webhook.

Armed with the GCM Token, I know the device/individual I want to send the notification to, my challenge now is how do I call Azure Notification Hub to target individual user?

Currently Azure Function only support Notification Hub binding with Templating, and that brings me to yet another challenge, how can I register for Azure notification hub from Android device using an installation?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but here's what I think you would need:

- Use [Notification Hubs tags](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message/) when you register devices on the client
- Bind the tag to your [function's tagExpression property](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-notification-hubs/#functionjson-for-azure-notification-hub-output-binding)

Refer to [Registration management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management/)
 post for more information about installation model.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the challenge is that the tagExpression is not dynamic. You have to set it up before hand. In my situation, I need to be sending to a different tag for each call, and the tag is not known until  the webhook call is made.

Comment: @ValOkafor, are you sure tagExpression is not dynamic? The point of binding is to be dynamic. Look at [the example where they do template registration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-notification-hubs/#azure-notification-hub-code-example-for-a-nodejs-timer-trigger) in a similar fashion: the location and message are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita G, Tag expression in of itself is dynamic, I am trying to use it from Azure Functions, where the default binding for Notification Hub is declared ahead of time. I do not want to stand up a Web API instance just to send a Notification. I am exploring work around.

Comment: I have updated my answer above to include sample code for sending push notifications to a dynamic tag triggered by queue. @ValOkafor- Let me know if that is what you are looking for. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

@Nikita G. guides correctly in overall.

I'd like to append implementation level knowledge.

Each individual can be managed by `tag` in Notification Hub as user can use multiple devices. Azure Notification Hub tag system is suitable to send a push for this situation. So, you could attach a tag like `user:34939` to identify user (not to identify device).

For this reason, you should think that your requirement is to identify `device` or to identiy `user`. Whatever cases, GCM token does not have to be attached to email link. Only tag value (userid) is enough to identify user or only Hub registration id is enough to identify device. The Hub registration id helps to manage registered devices regardless of APNS or GCM token.

About template, yes. Template is required during registration.

FYI, tag has 120 character length limits. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199385/361100

Comment: Great point, in a situation where the value for the users changes with each call, I am looking for a way to call Notification hub with a different tag for each call.

Answer (score 1):

tagExpression in NotificationHub is dynamic. Please see [Configuring notification tag for Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006649/configuring-notification-tag-for-azure-function) for more details. Also, Azure functions now supports sending notificaitons to GCM registrations. You need to set the Notification Platform on the Binding to GCM.

Here is a sample for sending WNS push notification to a dynamic tag that comes in as queueTrigger:

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
   {
     "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test-queue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
    },
    {
       "type": "notificationHub",
       "name": "notification",
       "hubName": "youthubname",
       "connection": "NOTIFICATIONHUB_AppSettingName",
       "direction": "out",
       "tagExpression": "{userIdTag}",
       "platform": "wns"
     }
   ],
   "disabled": false
}
```

C# QueueTrigger:

```
using System;

public static void Run(PushToTag myQueueItem, TraceWriter log, out string    notification)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.UserIdTag}");
    notification = "<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText01\"><text  id=\"1\">Test message</text></binding></visual></toast>";
}

public class PushToTag
{
     public string UserIdTag { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Queue Data

```
{"UserIdTag":"tag1" , "UserName":"joe"}
```

**Note: tag1 is the tag registered by the client**

You can send GCM notifications by selecting GCM in Notification Platform.

Comment: Can you explain, how the UserIdTag is bound to the myQueueItem.UserIdTag? I'm trying to implement this solution with a collection of inputs and a collection of outputs but I do net get the binding right.

Comment: I am only speculating here, but I believe the way works is that we have a queue binding input that gets mapped to the tagExpression.  I'm guessing the function is smart enough to map myQueueItem.UserIdTag to the notification output tag expression {userIdTag} and send the notification only to the person whose userIdTag matches.  Can you clarify how you are trying to use a collection of inputs and outputs?